# OidcSecurityService.getAccessToken() passes null as token first time

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-auth-oidc-client

We use an HttpInterceptor to add bearer token to our API requests. This is for an internal application that requires all users to be authenticated and authorized, even for the home page.

I have the code as shown below. On first render, for the first API call to render the first set of data, the token is `null`, and the token received first from the `getAccessToken()` subscription is also `null`. Everything is fine for subsequent API calls, even if the user presses `F5`.

We are running angular-auth-oidc-client@15.0.5 and angular 16.1. This became a problem when we upgraded from the previous version of angular-auth-oidc-client that did not rely on rxjs subscribe

```js
import { Injectable, Injector } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import {
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
} from "@angular/common/http";
import { OidcSecurityService } from "angular-auth-oidc-client";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { TokenValidatorService } from "../../services/token-validator.service";

export const UseOidcInterceptorHeader = "X-Oidc-Interceptor";

@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  token = null;
  constructor(
    public oidcSecurityService: OidcSecurityService,
    private tokenValidatorService: TokenValidatorService,
    private router: Router
  ) {
    this.oidcSecurityService.getAccessToken().subscribe((token) => {
      this.token = token
    });
  }

  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<unknown>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    // we do not intercept authentication calls to "companyAuthServer"
    if (req.url.includes("companyAuthServer")) {
      return next.handle(req);
    }

    if (this.token !== null) {
      if (!this.tokenValidatorService.checkUserIsInAdGroup(this.token)) {
        this.router.navigate(["/oidc/unauthorized"]);
      }

      const requestForward = req.clone({
        setHeaders: { Authorization: "Bearer " + this.token },
      });

      return next.handle(requestForward);
    } else {
      console.error(
        "OidcSecurityService, token not fetched: NO authorize header!",
        req.urlWithParams
      );
    }
    return next.handle(req);
  }
}
```

Comment: Even if we initialize the token with something else, like `token = "gibberish"`, then we still receive `null` as the first value from `subscribe()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you subscribe in your constructor and store the async result to `this.token`, of course `this.token` will not be set yet, the first time `intercept()` is called.

Instead of subscribing in the constructor, you can return an observable that waits for the async call to `getAccessToken()`, then switches to handling the next request:

```js
intercept(req: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
  if (req.url.includes("companyAuthServer")) {
    return next.handle(req);
  }

  return this.oidcSecurityService.getAccessToken().pipe(
    tap(token => {
      if(!token || !this.tokenValidatorService.checkUserIsInAdGroup(token)) {
        this.router.navigate(["/oidc/unauthorized"]);
      }
    }),
    map(token => req.clone({ setHeaders: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }}),
    switchMap(authRequest => next.handle(authRequest))
  );
}
```

Note: this isn't tested, so may need some adjustments, but hopefully gives you the idea.

Comment: We ended up with something similar to this solution. The important thing seems to call `getAccessToken()` in the intercept method itself, and not in the constructor.

I still don't know why we don't a `null` token the first time with this solution, which we do get with subscribe in the constructor.